# Atomic sequence counters in Google Datastore

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We have an application running in Google App Engine that, as part of its operation generates sequence numbers.  These numbers must meet the following criteria:

- They must fall between a specified start and end range
- They must be unique (until the end of the range is reached for some cases, in which case we can start from the beginning of the sequence again)
- They must be sequential (Random numbers are no good, even if they meet the other two criteria)

We did write code that attempts to ensure that the generated numbers are globally unique, but I can't share that code because a) it's rather convoluted, b) it's the property of my employer and c) it doesn't appear to work under heavy load.

I've done some reading up since the failure to ensure we're meeting the unique criteria and have found some information regarding [sharded counters](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters), but whilst I think this approach might help I still don't think it can guarantee that we are 100% certain to produce unique sequences.  My suspicion is that there's some latency in Datastore when it comes to upserts and that a delay between a counter being updated and that update reflecting in subsequent reads is to blame.  Besides there are not PHP examples of handling sharding (though we could probably figure it out from the other examples it would be nice if there was a working PHP example).

My proposed solution to this problem is as follows:

- Maintain the current value in the counter in both Memcache (which supports atomic incrementing of integers) and in Datastore (for persistence).  We might try to shard the counter in Datastore as well.
- When a request for a new number from a given sequence comes in:

  - Check Memcache for the current value.  If the data isn't in Memcache, populate it from Datastore
  - Do an atomic increment in Memcache
  - Use the value returned from Memcache for our process
  - Write the new counter value back to Datastore to ensure persistence

On the face of it this seems a reasonable solution but I'm worried there could still be edge cases where we end up with inconsistent counter values, especially if a lot of updates happen simultaneously.  While Memcache would ensure the atomicity of the returned values, I'm not certain the writes to Datastore would happen in the order of the requests and that at the end of it Datastore might not reflect the value in Memcache which could lead to problems if the app goes down and the incorrect value is loaded from Datastore when service is restored.

Are Datastore writes applied in the order they're received?  Can I guarantee that after all writes have been executed that the value in Datastore would match the value in Memcache?  Is there a better solution to this problem (other than switching to an SQL database with autoincrement/sequence support)?

Answer (score 1):

Sequential IDs in AppEngine datastore is a hard problem to tackle.

If you try do it one by one with persistence to datastore you'll hit transactions  throughput limit.

The best approach I can think of:

1. Use sharding to keep last N counter values.
2. Start transaction
3. Lock memcache entries before updating datastore shard (*you can use [`nds`](https://github.com/qedus/nds) package in Go or do in similar way*) and get all shard values from datastore by keys. Basically in Go just call `nds.GetMulti()` for all shards. The lock should have reasonable expiration value. For nds package it's 30 seconds.
4. Get shard ID and value for a shard with maximum value.
5. Update appropriate shard value **in datastore first** - store to db just single entity. For example you can have 10 shards with numbers 0-9 where shard number correspond to the last digit in counter value. So 23 would be mapped to shard 3.
6. Commit transaction (*exit out of transaction func/context*)
7. (Use memcache CAS (compare and swap) operations to update appropriate memcache value or delete it from memcache. Though it's not trivial task to do it right. You can read discussion I started on nds package - https://github.com/qedus/nds/issues/58

Basically you can do without memcache at all but memcache would save you money and may decrease latency (or not).

The important point is to lock memcache and update datastore first and then either delete from memcache or update using CAS. You plan does opposite.

Comment: Sorry but we're not using Go so we can't use the NDS library.  We might be able to roll our own PHP version

Comment: It's OK, I'm not author of the NDS lib. But it can give you some ideas and gotchas.